# Paypal Buy Now Button Variables Query

Tags: paypal

basic question I created the following variables in Buy Now button:

```
discount_amount=0 
discount_amount2=10.00 
discount_num=2
```

the idea is to give a 5 euro discount for each product when a client buys 2 or more of the product, but on the third purchase it subtracts 10 euros, how do i apply a 5 euro discount per product for 2 or more purchases?

Answer (score 0):

The Buy Now button's variables are not "smart" enough to meet your request. Maybe you have to write some JS code to calculate the total amount dynamically, or use select box to list the possible quantity like below

```html
<select name="amount">
 <option value="100">1 piece</option>
 <option value="190">2 pieces</option>
 <option value="285">3 pieces</option>
 ...
</select>
```